# Running stress utility as cronjob in centos vm

Tags: linux, cron, centos, centos6, stress-testing

I am trying to automate a test and have scheduled a cron job in centos vm for stress utility to trigger.

These are the steps I followed:

```
1) Install cron
2) crontab -e
3) */30 * * * * root stress --cpu 100 --io 4 --vm 2 --timeout 600s
```

The utility should wake up every 30 minutes and run for 600s.

Issue: Stress utility works perfectly fine when triggered manually from 
commond line. But when scheduled as a cron job it triggers but does not create
stress.

Eg: Manual trigger of job creates 100% stress on virtual machine.
When ran as cron job it creates just 3% stress.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in the `user` crontab. I think, this introduces a lower `nice` level, where `kernel` puts the process for lower priority when the process uses high CPU.

You can try a couple of things,

```
#1 Create a script from these commands
 ~]# cat << EOF > /usr/local/etc/get_stress.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   stress --cpu 100 --io 4 --vm 2 --timeout 600s
   EOF
 ~]# chmod u+x /usr/local/etc/get_stress.sh
 ~]# echo '*/30 * * * * root /usr/local/etc/get_stress.sh' > /etc/cron.d/stress-cron
```

Above should work as a system cron. If this doesn't work. check the `nice` level of the process while it is running.

```
 `ps axl | grep stress`
```

`NI` column should show the priority level it is running.